# Stuck at boot animation logo after flashing GSI image system

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, twrp, xiaomi, redmi

I know it seems be a repeated question but i have tried every possible solution i found, i have xiaomi redmi s2 with unlocked bootloader and custom treble TWRP recovery and i have a generic system image of AOSIP (GSI) downloaded from here [AOSiP-9.0-arm_aonly-GSI-20190217.img](https://get.aosiprom.com/GSI/)

and i have followed this tutorial to flash this image [How to flash a Generic System Image (GSI) on Project Treble supported devices.](https://www.xda-developers.com/flash-generic-system-image-project-treble-device/)

also tried this tutorial [How to install AOSP Extended (Android Pie) on Xiaomi Redmi S2 / Y2 YSL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKlQlIiOLMs&t=197s)

but my device stuck at boot animation and i have waited more than 20 min also i **tried these solutions:**

- wipe data/cache/dalvik-cache.
- flash no-verity-opt-encrypt.zip (dm-vertiy patch)
- flash magsik.zip to patch the boot.img
- reinstall stock boot.img only.
- try other GSI like AOSP/PIXEL/ViperOS/HavocOS , also it stuck.
- using fastboot instead of recovery.

I cannot figure out what the problem is. any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to flash miui rom then the gsi files/custom roms (xiaomi miui supported device only).
Method 1 :
Before flashing GSI files using fastboot first goto twrp and wipe data, cache , dalvik cache then flash the Miui rom for your phone after that flash GSI File using fastboot for your device.
Note: after flashing miui ROM don't boot to the os boot directly to the bootloader then flash the gsi file using.

```
fastboot flash system name-of-your-rom.img
```

Method 2 :
You can flash miui fastboot rom for your device using fastboot then flash gsi/custom rom
After flashing fastboot miui ROM for your device reboot to bootloader again using

```
fastboot reboot bootloader
```

Then flash gsi/custom ROM file using.

```
fastboot flash system your-system-image-name-here.img
```

Method 3 :
If you're flashing a custom rom compiled at .zip format you need to wipe system, data, cache partition then flash the miui rom after that flash the custom ROM you want. You don't need to restore your stock boot image when you've installed a custom ROM of course it won't boot and sometimes it does . In some device you need to patch the dm-verity on boot.img if you're installing twrp on a stock rom and flashing magisk doesn't fix your problem.

Comment: OP mentioned [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKlQlIiOLMs), so it is safe to conclude that he did use Twrp.

Comment: I think on xiaomi devices you need to flash miui ROM before the gsi files / custom ROMs.

Comment: I have already tried all these methods you are mentioned but  nothing changed

Comment: What miui ROM version you installed is it android 8.0+? Because gsi files only work on those android versions.

Comment: yes, it is oreo 8.1 with miui 10

Comment: All methods are tried and not working maybe booting is just long try waiting

Comment: Oh I forgot you need to install the required miui version the developer said before the custom rom installing, did you follow that?

Comment: I waited over 30min

Comment: What required miui version is ?

Comment: Here's an example try reading this https://www.google.com/amp/s/forum.xda-developers.com/redmi-s2/how-to/rom-lineage-os-15-1-project-treble-t3837281/amp/

Comment: Should i install the GSI image after flashing the required miui version or make a system wipe first?

Comment: After installing miui don't wipe system or it'll be all useless.. Note don't boot to system after flashing miui reboot to bootloader then flash gsi image.

Comment: I'm going to try your tutorial and i'll replying after finished.Thank you for help.

Comment: You did it, finally booted successfully.Thanks

Comment: Your welcome! Why not mark my answer green? It could help me a lot.